value not obtaining in lwc component
I am unable to display the value of orderNumber in the component. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?
import { LightningElement, wire, track  } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { EnclosingTabId, setTabLabel, setTabIcon } from 'lightning/platformWorkspaceApi';
import getPaymentInfoData from '@salesforce/apex/OrderDataController.GetPaymentInfo';
import PAYMENTINFO_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Payment_Info__c';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class Lwc_PaymentData extends LightningElement {
  
    sfscId;
    brand;
    orderNumber;
    paymentNumber;
    @track paymentInfoRec;
    @track paymentInfoObjectData;
    focusedTabInfo;
    isGrax;

    @wire(EnclosingTabId) enclosingTabId;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.getPaymentInfo();
    }


    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PAYMENTINFO_OBJECT })
    paymentInfo({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.paymentInfoObjectData = data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.paymentInfoObjectData));
            console.log('Amount__c Label => ', data.fields.Amount__c.label);
        }    
    }

    @track isSubmitting = true;
    @track orderLineRec = true;
    @track currentPageReference;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
      console.log('currentPageReference => ', currentPageReference);
      let reloadData = false;
      if (currentPageReference) {
        if(this.sfscId != null && this.sfscId != undefined && this.sfscId != currentPageReference.state?.c__SFSCID){
          reloadData = true;
        }
        this.sfscId = currentPageReference.state?.c__SFSCID;
        this.brand = currentPageReference.state?.c__brand;
        this.orderNumber = currentPageReference.state?.c__ordernumber;
        this.paymentNumber = currentPageReference.state?.c__paymentnumber;
        this.isGrax = currentPageReference.state?.c__grax;
      }
      if(reloadData == true){
        this.getPaymentInfo();
      }
    }

    getPaymentInfo() {
      this.isSubmitting = true;
      getPaymentInfoData({brand: this.brand, orderNumber: this.orderNumber, paymentNumber: this.paymentNumber, isGrax: this.isGrax, SFSCID: this.sfscId})
      .then(data => {
        this.paymentInfoRec = data;
        console.log('paymentInfoRec Name-->'+ this.paymentInfoRec.Name);
        console.log('paymentInfoRec-->'+ JSON.stringify(this.paymentInfoRec));
        setTabLabel(this.enclosingTabId, this.paymentNumber);
        setTabIcon(this.enclosingTabId, "custom:custom41");
      }).catch(error => {
        this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
        console.log('error-->'+JSON.stringify(error));
      }).finally(() => {this.isSubmitting = false; });
    }

    get orderUrl() {

      let orderNumber = this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r?.Order_Number__c?this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r.Order_Number__c:this.paymentInfoRec.Order_Id__c;
      return "/lightning/n/Order?c__SFSCID="+this.paymentInfoRec.Order__c + "&c__brand="+this.brand+ "&c__ordernumber="+orderNumber+"&c__grax="+this.isGrax;

      //  return "/lightning/n/Order?c__SFSCID="+this.paymentInfoRec.Order__c + "&c__brand="+this.brand+ "&c__ordernumber="+this.paymentInfoRec.Order_Id__c+"&c__grax="+this.isGrax;
    }

    /* get orderAccountName(){
        return this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r?.Name?this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r.Name:this.orderNumber;
    } */

    get orderNumber(){
        return this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r?.Order_Number__c?this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r.Order_Number__c:this.orderNumber;
    }

    toggleSection(event) {
        let buttonid = event.currentTarget.dataset.buttonid;
        let currentsection = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + buttonid + '"]');
        if (currentsection.className.search('slds-is-open') == -1) {
            currentsection.className = 'slds-section slds-is-open';
        } else {
            currentsection.className = 'slds-section slds-is-close';
        }
    }
}

Following is the html snippet:
                       <span class="slds-form-element__label"><lightning-formatted-text
                          value="Order"></lightning-formatted-text></span>
                          <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__static">
                                <lightning-formatted-url value={OrderUrl} label={orderNumber} target="_self" ></lightning-formatted-url>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      


You have two definitions of orderNumber:
orderNumber;

And:
get orderNumber(){
    return this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r?.Order_Number__c?this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r.Order_Number__c:this.orderNumber;
}

You're then trying to assign the value:
this.orderNumber = currentPageReference.state?.c__ordernumber;

Which shouldn't work, since you overrode the property, and you didn't define a set orderNumber(value).
You'll need to disambiguate these two uses, probably by removing the get orderNumber getter, since it appears to be redundant.
Or if you need a second copy of the value, you can change:
orderNumber;

To:
#orderNumber;

Which makes a separate, private variable to use, and wherever you want to use it, change this.orderNumber to this.#orderNumber.

Edit: There's a number of problems in your code. I won't highlight all the differences, though here's a few. First, the getPaymentInfo function should actually just be a wired method. Second, your code is a lot more complicated than it has to be. I can't verify that the following edits will work, but it should get you closer to your goal.
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { EnclosingTabId, setTabLabel, setTabIcon } from 'lightning/platformWorkspaceApi';
import getPaymentInfoData from '@salesforce/apex/OrderDataController.GetPaymentInfo';
import PAYMENTINFO_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Payment_Info__c';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class Lwc_PaymentData extends LightningElement {
  // Cleaned up some properties
  // @track removed, is not necessary in this code

  sfscId;
  brand;
  orderNumber;
  paymentNumber;
  paymentInfoRec = {};
  isGrax;
  isSubmitting;

  @wire(EnclosingTabId) enclosingTabId;

  // Unused here, assuming this is for the UI?
  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PAYMENTINFO_OBJECT }) paymentInfoObjectData;

  @wire(CurrentPageReference)
  getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
    let sfscId = currentPageReference.state?.c__SFSCID || "";
    let brand = currentPageReference.state?.c__brand || "";
    let orderNumber = currentPageReference.state?.c__ordernumber || "";
    let paymentNumber = currentPageReference.state?.c__paymentnumber || "";
    let isGrax = currentPageReference.state?.c__grax || "";
    // Turn on spinner if the page state changed, which triggers the wire function
    this.isSubmitting = sfscId !== this.sfscId || brand !== this.brand || orderNumber !== this.orderNumber || paymentNumber !== this.paymentNumber || isGrax !== this.isGrax;
    this.sfscId = sfscId;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    this.paymentNumber = paymentNumber;
    this.isGrax = isGrax;
  }

  //
  @wire(getPaymentInfoData, { brand: '$brand', orderNumber: '$orderNumber', paymentNumber: '$paymentNumber', isGrax: '$isGrax', SFSCID: '$sfscId' })
  handlePaymentInfo({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.paymentInfoRec = data;
      setTabLabel(this.enclosingTabId, this.paymentNumber);
      setTabIcon(this.enclosingTabId, "custom:custom41");
    }
    if (error) {
      // deal with the error
    }
    if (data || error) {
      this.isSubmitting = false;
    }
  }

  get orderUrl() {
    let orderNumber = this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r?.Order_Number__c ? this.paymentInfoRec.Order__r.Order_Number__c : this.paymentInfoRec.Order_Id__c;
    return "/lightning/n/Order?c__SFSCID=" + this.paymentInfoRec.Order__c + "&c__brand=" + this.brand + "&c__ordernumber=" + orderNumber + "&c__grax=" + this.isGrax;
  }

  toggleSection(event) {
    let buttonid = event.currentTarget.dataset.buttonid;
    let currentsection = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + buttonid + '"]');
    if (currentsection.className.search('slds-is-open') == -1) {
      currentsection.className = 'slds-section slds-is-open';
    } else {
      currentsection.className = 'slds-section slds-is-close';
    }
  }
}

I have not tested this code, so there may yet be other errors, but this should get you started.

No, I don't need a copy. I removed the getter. Still not working :(

@user149369 You actually have more problems in your code than I realized. I'll edit in an updated version.

I changed the html to:  and the order number is displaying now. Need to get the hyperlink working.

@user149369 I made some edits. As for the last problem, JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. It should be orderUrl, not OrderUrl.

Wow that worked! this was the issue :) All ok now, thanks!
